# Classes to test aren't within scope of test package

Tags: android

```
Android Studio 0.5.1
```

I have exported my eclipse projects `LocationLab` and `LocationLabTest` using Generate gradle build files.

I then imported these into Android Studio. I have set the module dependancy for LocationLabTest as this depends on LocationLab in Project Stucture.

It seems that the classes I need to test aren't within the scope of the test package.

Problem is that LocationLabTest cannot find the import package for LocationLab package course.labs.locationlab

In the LocationLabTest manifest file it has a red color for TargetPackage `android:targetPackage="course.labs.locationlab"`.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Here is the screenshot of my structure:
[image]

build.grade (LocationLabTest)

```
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile project(':LocationLab')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.1'
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
    buildTypes {
    }
}
```

build.grade (LocationLab)

```
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.1'

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Under Gradle, the tests aren't in a separate module from the code under test; the tests live in the same module, with the source in a different directory. Gradle generates the test APK's **AndroidManifest.xml** file automatically, so that's not something you specify.

In your main module's **build.gradle** file, you've already got a test folder set up:

```
    // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
```

so you should move your test code into that folder. You can find documentation on setting up tests in Gradle at http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Testing